# Concatenate of firstName and lastName and perfom searching on this 2 property using Gremlin queries

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

```
    "label":”employee”,
    "id": "64c268cc-6a39-4eba-a312-79103a97b837",
    "entityType":"employee",
    "organizationId": "d7081ebb-4685-4cb5-ba24-027eeb815a27",
    "floorId":”36577019-0587-4a15-b784-4b2b0df7a1da”,
    "officeId": "7632d466-66e2-4c38-a40b-9d1deec61e69",
    "firstName": "Sarfaraz",
    "lastName": "Shaikh",
    "phoneNumber": "9874152362",
    "department": "Data",
    "teams": "[.Net","Devops"],
    "deviceId": "RAHS898HAJHS”,
    "devicetype": 1 ,  
    "timestamp": 1586173968,
    "isActive": True/False
```

Above is the vertex property for employee, I want to perform concatenation on firstName and lastName and also searching on this properties using gremlin queries, Azure cosmos graphDB supports only case sensitive data, and I am not able to perform case sensitive search.

Let say in the database if firstName property store 'sarfaraz' and I search for 'Sa' it should give me this result 'sarfaraz'.

Answer (score 1):

The current Gremlin Query Language does not have any string manipulation capabilities built in so you can not for example do something like concatenate two strings using Gremlin steps. If the graph database you are using supports in line lambdas/closures then you can do it that way but a lot of graph DBs prevent that for security reasons among others. The Gremlin text predicates are case sensitive. Some graph DBs support integration with an external index such as Elastic Search. In those cases, case insensitive search is possible.